# Reference request: examples where probabilistic methods make theoretical contributions to deterministic fields?

Tags: probability, soft-question

This idea came up during a discussion on whether you need randomness for the concept of probability to be valid, and if not, what is needed. I argued that having a stationary, recurrent sequence, is sufficient and gave a couple examples that seemed interesting:

### The Sin "Distribution"

Take a typical sine wave. Now, we can construct a distribution function as follows:

$$F_{\sin}(c) := \frac{\text{Leb}\{x \in [0,2\pi]:\sin(x)\leq c\})}{2\pi}$$

You get the following function:

[image]

Which gives a histogram looking like this:

[image]

Note that at this point, I have not said anything is random, just that the Lebesgue measure of intervals of the type $\{f(x)\leq c\}$ produce a function that converges to a valid CDF.

My second example was the entire field of pseudorandom number generators. These are deterministic functions that nevertheless satisfy statistical tests for randomness to a high degree of accuracy (i.e., over a large range of autocorrelations).

My question is more of a request: are there examples/papers where probabilistic ideas have significantly helped advance the some fundamentally deterministic theory/field?

One example is the "probabilistic method" ala Erdos, but are there others?

Comment: The construction of probability is unrelated to "randomness" (in your own words it is a deterministic field, as in fact is any other mathematical field). However, some properties of some particular probabilities (better say probability measures) are often interpreted as corresponding to some degree of randomness. And as you also mention it, randomness appears in other fields as well, but it is not appropriate to deduce that since we use the same word, that these randomnesses are related. Incidentally, how would you define "random"?

Comment: @Jonas well, "random" to me is an epistemological question: does there exist a function such that we can predict all future values given the current value or current "time" index.

Comment: On the other hand, one can reply to your question in the title, provided that "random" is out of the game: examples of fields where probabilistic ideas play a major role are ergodic theory, Hamiltonian dynamics, and their further developments for example into smooth ergodic theory and the thermodynamic formalism.

Comment: I don't know also what "predict" means...

Comment: @Jonas that a sequence $X_i$ is random iff there does not exist method for calculating $X_s$ given $X_t$ for $\forall s>t$

Comment: Ah, so you would put any "pseudorandom number generator" out of the game... But really you need to then define what "there does not exist method" means.

Comment: @Jonas (+1) haha..Ok ok...I get it. There is a tad bit of circularity here, in fact, I'm not sure the philosophical community has come up with an uncontroversial definition of "random"...like I said, I take it to be a philosophical assertion. We can't prove something is random with 100% certainty. All we can say is that very little information about future values of a sequence appears to be provided by the past values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernstein [gave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions) a constructive proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem based on probability:

> Bernstein, S. N., Démonstration du Théorème de Weierstrass fondée sur le calcul des Probabilités, Comm. Soc. Math. Kharkov 2.Series XIII No.1 (1912), 1-2.

See [History of Approximation Theory |Historical Papers](http://www.math.technion.ac.il/hat/papers.html).

Comment: Perfect example. Thanks!